# Getting stuck with linear chart and tooltip using D3. The tooltip only show the first value and date and the last

Tags: csv, d3.js, charts, tooltip

- Hi there,

The chart should showing me in a tooltip the value of the stock and date as I move my mouse over the linear line. But as you can see, the tooltip wont move with mouse and only show 2 values anda dates. The very first one and the last.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwUAh.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T05M.jpg)

So, when you move the mouse over the line, you should see a red circle and a tooltip showing the value "R$" and the date that represents the point you are with your mouse on it.

In the next image you can see that there is not a exactly an error occurring:

using visual studio with liveserver extension.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHWMW.jpg)

I tried chat GPT and got looping in solution that didnt worked.

I tried a brand new code with GPT and got same issue.

**When I try this code with a similar .CSV the chart works perfect.
**
**Script.js file:**

```
// Função assíncrona que desenha um gráfico de linha com D3.js a partir dos dados em um arquivo CSV.
async function draw() {

  // Importa o conjunto de dados do arquivo CSV usando o método await para garantir que o processo de leitura seja concluído antes de continuar.
  const dataset = await d3.csv('ccm_esalq.csv');
  console.log(dataset); // <-- Adiciona um log do dataset aqui  ccm_esalq.csv
  
  // Define as funções para acessar os valores do eixo x e do eixo y
  const parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');
  const xAccessor = d => parseDate(d['date']);
  const yAccessor = d => parseFloat(d['brl']); //brl

  // Definir as dimensões do gráfico
  let dimensions = {
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
    margins: 50,
  };
  // Calcula as dimensões do gráfico sem as margens. 
  dimensions.ctrWidth = dimensions.width - dimensions.margins * 2
  dimensions.ctrHeight = dimensions.height - dimensions.margins * 2

  // Cria o elemento SVG para desenhar o gráfico (<div id="chart"> deve constar no .html)
  const svg = d3.select('#chart')
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", dimensions.width)
    .attr("height", dimensions.height)

 // Cria um grupo SVG para conter todos os elementos do gráfico, usando as margens definidas.
  const ctr = svg.append("g") // <g>
    .attr("transform",`translate(${dimensions.margins}, ${dimensions.margins})`)

// Define o elemento do tooltip e o ponto a ser exibido quando o mouse estiver sobre o gráfico.
  const tooltip = d3.select('#tooltip')
  const tooltipDot = ctr.append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('fill', '#fc8781')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .style('pointer-events', 'none')

  // Cria as escalas para os eixos x e y usando os valores mínimos e máximos do conjunto de dados
  const yExtent = d3.extent(dataset, yAccessor);
  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(yExtent)
    .range([dimensions.ctrHeight, 0])
    .nice()

  const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset, xAccessor))
    .range([0, dimensions.ctrWidth])

  console.log(xScale(xAccessor(dataset[0])), dataset[0]);

  // Cria um gerador de linhas para o conjunto de dados
  const lineGenerator = d3.line()
    .x((d) => xScale(xAccessor(d)))
    .y((d) => yScale(yAccessor(d)))

  console.log(lineGenerator(dataset));
  
  // Desenha a linha do gráfico usando o gerador de linhas e o conjunto de dados
  ctr.append('path')
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr('d', lineGenerator)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', '#30475e')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)

   // Adiciona os eixos x e y ao gráfico
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    .tickFormat((d) => `R$${d}`)

  ctr.append('g')
    .call(yAxis)

  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)

  ctr.append('g')
    .style('transform', `translateY(${dimensions.ctrHeight}px)`)
    .call(xAxis)

  // (tooltip) Adiciona um retângulo transparente ao gráfico para detectar quando o mouse está sobre ele
  ctr.append('rect')
    .attr('width', dimensions.ctrWidth)
    .attr('height', dimensions.ctrHeight)
    .style('opacity', 0)
    // Define eventos de escuta para o retângulo.
    .on('touchmouse mousemove', function (event) {
      // Captura a posição do mouse em relação ao retângulo.
      const mousePos = d3.pointer(event, this)
      // Converte a posição x do mouse para a data correspondente no eixo x.
      const date = xScale.invert(mousePos[0])

      // Encontra o índice do item no dataset correspondente à data capturada.
      const bisector = d3.bisector(xAccessor).left;
      const index = bisector(dataset, date);
      // Obtém o item anterior na lista (esquerda).
      const stock = dataset[index - 1] || dataset[index]; // Adicione esta linha para obter o item anterior ou o próprio item atual caso seja o primeiro

      // Atualiza o círculo do tooltip para a posição do item correspondente a data.
      tooltipDot.style('opacity', 1)
        .attr('cx', xScale(xAccessor(stock)))
        .attr('cy', yScale(yAccessor(stock)))
        .raise()
      // Exibe o tooltip na posição do item correspondente a data.
      tooltip.style('display', 'block')
        .style('top', yScale(yAccessor(stock)) - 20 + 'px')
        .style('left', xScale(xAccessor(stock)) + "px")
      // Atualiza o texto do tooltip com o valor e a data correspondentes.
      tooltip.select('.price')
        .text(`R$${yAccessor(stock)}`)

      const dateFormatter = d3.timeFormat('%B %-d, %Y')

      tooltip.select('.date')
        .text(`${dateFormatter(xAccessor(stock))}`)
    })
    // Esconde o tooltip quando o mouse deixa a área do gráfico.
    .on('mouseleave', function (event) {
      tooltipDot.style('opacity', 0)

      tooltip.style('display', 'none')
    })
}
// Chama a função para desenhar o gráfico.
draw()
```

**.Css file:**

```
body{
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

#chart{
  margin: 25px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

#tooltip {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.price {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**.HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>D3 Line Chart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart">
    <div id="tooltip">
      <div class="price"></div>
      <div class="date"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and part of .csv file

```
date,brl,usd
2023-04-06,80.24,15.86
2023-04-05,80.89,16
2023-04-04,81.12,15.95
2023-04-03,82.4,16.24
2023-03-31,82.6,16.29
2023-03-30,82.9,16.25
2023-03-29,83.17,16.18
2023-03-28,83.39,16.14
2023-03-27,84,16.12
2023-03-24,84.18,16.04
2023-03-23,83.91,15.86
2023-03-22,84.36,16.17
2023-03-21,84.46,16.11
2023-03-20,84.66,16.15
2023-03-17,85.24,16.16
2023-03-16,85.37,16.28
2023-03-15,85.49,16.15
2023-03-14,85.42,16.25
2023-03-13,85.61,16.25
2023-03-10,85.32,16.36
2023-03-09,85.47,16.65
2023-03-08,86.03,16.73
2023-03-07,85.84,16.54
2023-03-06,86.15,16.68
2023-03-03,86.22,16.59
2023-03-02,86.36,16.59
2023-03-01,86.11,16.57
2023-02-28,86.08,16.49
2023-02-27,86.4,16.63
2023-02-24,85.83,16.49
2023-02-23,86.22,16.8
2023-02-22,86.06,16.65
2023-02-17,85.73,16.61
2023-02-16,86.24,16.52
2023-02-15,86.06,16.5
2023-02-14,86.26,16.59
2023-02-13,85.86,16.57
2023-02-10,86.03,16.47
2023-02-09,85.96,16.31
2023-02-08,84.9,16.36
2023-02-07,84.87,16.32
2023-02-06,85.12,16.45
2023-02-03,84.98,16.54
2023-02-02,85.04,16.89
2023-02-01,85.76,16.85
2023-01-31,85.49,16.83
2023-01-30,84.95,16.62
2023-01-27,84.74,16.58
2023-01-26,84.88,16.73
2023-01-25,85.22,16.79
2023-01-24,85.17,16.55
2023-01-23,85.43,16.44
2023-01-20,85.33,16.4
2023-01-19,85.38,16.5
2023-01-18,85.9,16.65
2023-01-17,86.19,16.87
2023-01-16,86.39,16.77
2023-01-13,86.87,17.05
2023-01-12,86.86,17.05
2023-01-11,87.19,16.81
2023-01-10,87.33,16.79
2023-01-09,87.27,16.61
2023-01-06,87.5,16.69
2023-01-05,87.72,16.36
2023-01-04,86.35,15.83
2023-01-03,86.07,15.8
2023-01-02,86.09,16.06
2022-12-29,86.07,16.3
2022-12-28,86.42,16.45
2022-12-27,86.61,16.39
2022-12-26,85.79,16.47
2022-12-23,85.8,16.61
2022-12-22,85.58,16.53
2022-12-21,85.82,16.51
2022-12-20,85.98,16.51
2022-12-19,86.05,16.21
2022-12-16,86.44,16.32
2022-12-15,85.91,16.14
2022-12-14,85.79,16.12
2022-12-13,86,16.18
2022-12-12,86.15,16.18
2022-12-09,86.08,16.43
2022-12-08,85.9,16.48
2022-12-07,86.19,16.54
2022-12-06,86.1,16.34
2022-12-05,85.54,16.2
2022-12-02,86.03,16.47
2022-12-01,86,16.52
2022-11-30,86.2,16.55
2022-11-29,85.76,16.21
2022-11-28,85.96,16.02
2022-11-25,85.48,15.8
2022-11-24,85.87,16.16
2022-11-23,85.51,15.92
2022-11-22,85.19,15.83
2022-11-21,85.08,16.02
2022-11-18,84.77,15.8
2022-11-17,84.06,15.48
2022-11-16,83.69,15.54
2022-11-14,84,15.76
2022-11-11,83.74,15.68
2022-11-10,84.48,15.65
2022-11-09,84.76,16.37
2022-11-08,85.3,16.5
2022-11-07,85.19,16.52
2022-11-04,84.95,16.87
2022-11-03,84.76,16.58
2022-11-01,85.11,16.65
2022-10-31,85.35,16.5
2022-10-28,85.69,16.12
2022-10-27,85.35,16.11
2022-10-26,85.12,15.84
2022-10-25,84.91,15.98
2022-10-24,85.08,16.09
2022-10-21,85.28,16.57
2022-10-20,85.21,16.31
2022-10-19,85.41,16.2
2022-10-18,85.38,16.23
2022-10-17,84.86,16.03
2022-10-14,84.67,15.89
2022-10-13,84.42,15.99
2022-10-11,83.86,15.91
2022-10-10,83.5,16.11
2022-10-07,83.05,15.89
2022-10-06,83.04,15.96
2022-10-05,82.91,16.02
2022-10-04,83.27,16.09
2022-10-03,84.14,16.25
2022-09-30,84.42,15.7
2022-09-29,84.24,15.61
2022-09-28,84.25,15.76
2022-09-27,84.72,15.75
2022-09-26,84.58,15.69
2022-09-23,84.54,16.1
2022-09-22,84.56,16.54
2022-09-21,84.24,16.3
2022-09-20,84.21,16.32
2022-09-19,84.02,16.27
2022-09-16,84.35,16.04
2022-09-15,84.55,16.13
2022-09-14,84.28,16.27
2022-09-13,83.72,16.13
2022-09-12,83.95,16.49
2022-09-09,83.43,16.2
2022-09-08,83.25,15.98
2022-09-06,83.54,15.94
2022-09-05,83.26,16.16
2022-09-02,83.39,16.11
2022-09-01,83.66,15.98
2022-08-31,83.94,16.14
2022-08-30,83.73,16.39
2022-08-29,83.8,16.67
2022-08-26,83.6,16.48
2022-08-25,83.31,16.25
2022-08-24,82.77,16.2
2022-08-23,82.69,16.21
2022-08-22,81.9,15.87
2022-08-19,82.16,15.88
2022-08-18,82.1,15.87
2022-08-17,82.77,16
2022-08-16,82.11,15.95
2022-08-15,81.41,15.98
2022-08-12,81.55,16.09
2022-08-11,81.94,15.87
2022-08-10,82.76,16.25
2022-08-09,81.63,15.89
2022-08-08,82.05,16.04
2022-08-05,81.91,15.85
2022-08-04,82.24,15.76
2022-08-03,82.41,15.62
2022-08-02,82.58,15.64
2022-08-01,82.64,15.94
2022-07-29,82.93,16.02
2022-07-28,81.78,15.84
2022-07-27,81.4,15.51
2022-07-26,81.27,15.18
2022-07-25,80.2,14.92
2022-07-22,80.06,14.55
2022-07-21,80.85,14.72
2022-07-20,81.41,14.91
2022-07-19,81.67,15.07
2022-07-18,82.36,15.19
2022-07-15,82.46,15.25
2022-07-14,82.58,15.2
2022-07-13,82.73,15.3
2022-07-12,83.12,15.29
2022-07-11,82.36,15.34
2022-07-08,81.5,15.48
2022-07-07,81.68,15.28
2022-07-06,82.19,15.18
2022-07-05,82.6,15.32
2022-07-04,83.24,15.63
2022-07-01,83.16,15.63
2022-06-30,83.55,15.97
2022-06-29,84.85,16.33
2022-06-28,83.9,15.93
2022-06-27,84.75,16.21
2022-06-24,85.65,16.29
2022-06-23,85.92,16.43
2022-06-22,87.04,16.84
2022-06-21,87.15,16.92
2022-06-20,87.42,16.86
2022-06-17,86.32,16.79
2022-06-15,86.25,17.16
2022-06-14,86.42,16.81
2022-06-13,85.41,16.67
2022-06-10,85.42,17.15
2022-06-09,85.85,17.48
2022-06-08,85.86,17.59
2022-06-07,85.56,17.56
2022-06-06,84.8,17.66
2022-06-03,85.07,17.78
2022-06-02,85.52,17.84
2022-06-01,85.8,17.88
2022-05-31,86.25,18.15
2022-05-30,86.84,18.28
2022-05-27,86.9,18.34
2022-05-26,86.99,18.27
2022-05-25,87.33,18.15
2022-05-24,87.43,18.13
2022-05-23,88.03,18.29
2022-05-20,88.48,18.17
2022-05-19,89.23,18.16
2022-05-18,89.28,17.9
2022-05-17,89.09,18.03
2022-05-16,87.97,17.44
2022-05-13,86.54,17.12
2022-05-12,86.4,16.79
2022-05-11,86.08,16.75
2022-05-10,85.83,16.75
2022-05-09,86.15,16.71
2022-05-06,86.63,17.08
2022-05-05,87.41,17.38
2022-05-04,87.55,17.83
2022-05-03,87.6,17.64
2022-05-02,87.87,17.34
2022-04-29,88.25,17.83
2022-04-28,88.38,17.9
2022-04-27,88.21,17.77
2022-04-26,88.51,17.74
2022-04-25,88.71,18.2
2022-04-22,87.93,18.33
2022-04-20,87.87,19
2022-04-19,88.03,18.84
2022-04-18,87.63,18.81
2022-04-14,87.3,18.61
2022-04-13,87.56,18.69
2022-04-12,88.17,18.85
2022-04-11,88.9,18.98
2022-04-08,89.02,18.92
2022-04-07,89.06,18.77
2022-04-06,89.46,18.95
2022-04-05,90.19,19.37
2022-04-04,91.55,19.85
2022-04-01,92.04,19.71
2022-03-31,93.09,19.55
2022-03-30,92.7,19.38
2022-03-29,92.77,19.49
2022-03-28,96.16,20.16
2022-03-25,96.98,20.41
2022-03-24,99.2,20.55
2022-03-23,99.93,20.65
2022-03-22,101.29,20.59
2022-03-21,102.63,20.72
2022-03-18,102.59,20.46
2022-03-17,103.57,20.56
2022-03-16,103.74,20.32
2022-03-15,103.87,20.15
2022-03-14,103.9,20.26
2022-03-11,103.57,20.5
2022-03-10,101.42,20.21
2022-03-09,101.25,20.21
2022-03-08,101.36,20.05
2022-03-07,100.19,19.73
2022-03-04,98.15,19.32
2022-03-03,97.72,19.45
2022-03-02,97.2,19.02
2022-02-25,97.34,18.92
2022-02-24,96.89,18.93
2022-02-23,96.85,19.36
2022-02-22,96.8,19.11
2022-02-21,96.52,18.9
2022-02-18,96.49,18.78
2022-02-17,96.51,18.67
2022-02-16,96.53,18.82
2022-02-15,96.55,18.63
2022-02-14,95.98,18.4
2022-02-11,97.05,18.57
2022-02-10,97.08,18.58
2022-02-09,96.93,18.57
2022-02-08,97.14,18.49
2022-02-07,96.97,18.44
2022-02-04,97.13,18.24
2022-02-03,96.82,18.29
2022-02-02,97.14,18.38
2022-02-01,97.4,18.48
2022-01-31,97.42,18.37
2022-01-28,97.4,18.06
2022-01-27,97.37,17.94
2022-01-26,97.9,18.11
2022-01-25,97.76,17.97
2022-01-24,97.93,17.8
2022-01-21,98.33,18.02
2022-01-20,98.13,18.14
2022-01-19,97.7,17.88
2022-01-18,97.39,17.53
2022-01-17,97.16,17.59
2022-01-14,96.77,17.52
2022-01-13,96.5,17.48
2022-01-12,95.27,17.21
2022-01-11,95.13,17.05
2022-01-10,94.43,16.65
2022-01-07,93.52,16.6
2022-01-06,93.28,16.41
2022-01-05,92.81,16.3
2022-01-04,92.72,16.3
2022-01-03,92.01,16.25
```

need help to fix!

Comment: problem fixed.

d3.csv("esalq.csv").then(data => {
  // Parse the date and convert the usd to a number
  const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  data.forEach(d => {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.usd = +d.usd;
  });

  // Sort the data array by date -- THIS IS THE FIX
  data.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);



-From DataVizDad

can close the topic